# Twitter API POST media/upload (chunked) error "Not found"

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

Why when I APPEND the chunked data it returns

> "{"request":"/1.1/media/upload.json","error":"Not found."}" ?

FINALIZE it returns:

> "{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}"

```
var CHUNK_SIZE = 1024, 
    buffer = new Buffer(CHUNK_SIZE),
    filePath = './web.mp4',
    data, segment_index,
    media = null;


async.series([
    function (callback) { 
        request.post({
            url: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", oauth: oauth, host: "upload.twitter.com", protocol: "https:", formData: {
                command: "INIT",
                media_type: 'video/mp4',
                total_bytes: 854429
            }
        }, function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
            media = body;
            segment_index = 0;
            callback();
        });

    },
    function (callback) {
        var fd = fs.openSync(filePath, 'r');

        var nread = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE, null);

        if (nread === 0) {
        } else {

            if (nread < CHUNK_SIZE) {
                data = buffer.slice(0, nread);
            } else {
                data = buffer;
            }

            request.post({
                url: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", oauth: oauth, host: "upload.twitter.com", protocol: "https:", formData: {
                    command: "APPEND",
                    media_id: JSON.parse(media).media_id,
                    segment_index: segment_index,
                    media: data.toString('base64')
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'base64'
                }
            }, function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });

        }

        callback();

    }
], function (err) { 
    if (err) return null;
});
```

This code is for testing purpose, I read the first 1024 chunk to see if the API response is correctly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem might be here:

`JSON.parse(media).media_id`

try:

`JSON.parse(media).media_id_string`

Answer (score 1):

What's the response from your INIT call?

The NOT_FOUND exception in your APPEND calls means the Media ID you provided can't be found. That would indicate that the INIT call didn't succeed.

I don't see your FINALIZE code here, but the error could be the result of calling that command an incomplete upload that failed in INIT.

I've got a shell script available here that demonstrates the overall flow (not meant for production, just testing and demonstration purposes):

https://gist.github.com/brandonblack/bb3feaff9f0a2cad2d74

We should also have this implemented in the Ruby SDK for the Ads API very soon. Feel free to follow that issue, it might serve as a good reference implementation:

https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-ruby-ads-sdk/issues/7